# Package MuMIn: function "r.rsquaredGLMM" does not work anymore

Tags: r, mumin

I frequently used extracted marginal and conditional R^2 from mixed models using r.rsquaredGLMM(mod) from package MuMIn. Since today this doesn't work any more and I get the following error:
 **Error in r.rsquaredGLMM(mod) : could not find function "r.rsquaredGLMM"**

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? 
Thanks, Katharina

Below a code example:

````
library(MuMIn)
mod <- lmer(Reaction~Subject + (1|Days), data=sleepstudy)
r.rsquaredGLMM(mod)
```
````

Comment: You can do a quick check if the required package is loaded or not? Using ``(.packages())``

Comment: Problem solved! I did remove and reinstall the Package MuMIn and now it is working properly again.